# JBoss AS 7 throwing 'java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException' during start

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-weld

I'm using JBoss 7.1.3 (built from sources) with Ubuntu 13.10 64 bits and open-jdk 7. And all the application works fine. Works fine with other developers using Windows and other Linux too (with java 7 from Oracle and OpenJDK).

Now I'm trying to start the application in another machine (a virtual machine with Redhat 6 - 64 bits with open-jdk 7)
Using extacly same jboss from other machine (zip the jboss folder and unzip in the new machine) and the application do not start anymore.

I tryed with a clean JBoss 7.1.3, 7.2.0 and even WildFly 8.1.0.CR1 but the error persists.

I also compile the application sources on the new machine, but the error persists.

Follow the error:

```
20:49:12,388 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."vendas-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."vendas-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldService: com.google.common.collect.ComputationException: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:83)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
Caused by: com.google.common.collect.ComputationException: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:397)
at org.jboss.weld.resources.SharedObjectCache.getTypeClosure(SharedObjectCache.java:82)
at org.jboss.weld.resources.SharedObjectFacade.getTypeClosure(SharedObjectFacade.java:65)
at org.jboss.weld.introspector.TypeClosureLazyValueHolder.computeValue(TypeClosureLazyValueHolder.java:52)
at org.jboss.weld.introspector.TypeClosureLazyValueHolder.computeValue(TypeClosureLazyValueHolder.java:31)
at org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:34)
at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.AbstractWeldAnnotated.getTypeClosure(AbstractWeldAnnotated.java:193)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractBean.initTypes(AbstractBean.java:187)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.<init>(ManagedBean.java:280)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.of(ManagedBean.java:253)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.createManagedBean(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:212)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.createBeans(BeanDeployer.java:139)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:204)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:350)
at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:82)
at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:60) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:53) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:95) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperclass(ClassRepository.java:84) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
at java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:696) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.discoverFromClass(HierarchyDiscovery.java:126)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.discoverTypes(HierarchyDiscovery.java:95)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.init(HierarchyDiscovery.java:74)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.getTypeClosure(HierarchyDiscovery.java:58)
at org.jboss.weld.resources.SharedObjectCache$4.apply(SharedObjectCache.java:58)
at org.jboss.weld.resources.SharedObjectCache$4.apply(SharedObjectCache.java:55)
at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:355)
at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:393)
... 20 more
```

Is there any clue?

thanks

Comment: There are some stranges behaviors like:  
1) this error only occours in a few machines (but with same linux version, distro version, java version and same project version)  
2) when clone the entire jboss (zip) from another working jboss (from another working machine), still getting this error
3) sometimes we need to FORMAT the "problematic" machine to fix the problem (but sometimes even formatting, still getting this error)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your maven  artifactId ?
That strangely solved my issue (while reinstalling jboss and restarting the PC didn't).

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue with latest Payara 4.1 173 (I know, not JBoss/WildFly but it utilizes same WELD engine). I was able to fix this by doing the following:

- re-install Payara's `lib` and `modules` directory (within `glassfish` directory)
- make sure to keep `mariadb*.sql` in, else the JDBC resources won't work
- purge `~/personal_domain/osgi-cache/`

This is the place where JARs are being collected, maybe there is a similar place? If you downgrade e.g. javax.faces.jar from 2.3.2 (beta) to 2.2.14 (bundles with Payara) and you don't purge `osgi-cache`, you still have 2.3.2 and not 2.2.14 because it is being loaded from `osgi-cache`. Upgrading such JARs works fine, not downgrading.

Again, I know it is not WildFly/JBoss, but this did solve my issue.

I thought this might be worthing it because that same exception drove me crazy here. I also added a new logger `org.jboss.weld` with `FINEST` as log-level and saw that it successfully parsed the annotations and still the exception came. I also tried to remove public constructors from all converters and validators but no avail. Only until I did the mentioned above steps, I was able to recover Payara.